# Fixed interval micro-batch and once time micro-batch trigger mode don't work with Parquet file sink

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

I'm trying to consume data on Kafka topic and push consumed messages to HDFS with parquet format.
I'm using pyspark (2.4.5) to create Spark structed streaming process. The problem is my Spark job is endless and no data is pushed to HDFS.

```py
process = (
    # connect to kafka brokers
    (
        spark.readStream.format("kafka")
        .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "brokers_list")
        .option("subscribe", "kafka_topic")
        .option("startingOffset", "earliest")
        .option("includeHeaders", "true")
        .load()
        .writeStream.format("parquet")
        .trigger(once=True). # tried with processingTime argument and have same result
        .option("path", f"hdfs://hadoop.local/draft")
        .option("checkpointLocation", "hdfs://hadoop.local/draft_checkpoint")
        .start()
    )
)
```

My Spark session's UI is liked this:
[image: Spark UI]

More details on stage:
[image: Spark stage details]

I check status on my notebook and got this:

```py
{
    'message': 'Processing new data',
    'isDataAvailable': True,
    'isTriggerActive': True
}
```

When I check my folder on HDFS, there is no data is loaded. Only a directory named `_spark_metadata` is created in the `output_location` folder.

I don't face this problem if I remove the line of triggerMode `trigger(processingTime="1 minute")`. When I use default trigger mode, spark create a lot of small parquet file in the output location, this is inconvenient.
Does 2 trigger mode `processingTime` and `once` support for parquet file sink?
If I have to use the default trigger mode, how can I handle the gigantic number of tiny files created in my HDFS system?

Comment: Are you sure about the code you shared above?
`parsed_df` is used for writestream as opposed to `df`?

Comment: thank you, that's my mistake. I just updated my code.

Comment: Glad i could help, do you mind closing the question.

Comment: I just share the wrong code, I'm still facing this problem.

Comment: I have tried with mode `trigger(once=True)` and nothing is written in HDFS also.

Comment: Had you solved the issue?

Comment: yes, I think the problem is just the data in the streaming is too great and my startingOffset is configured with 'earliest'. You may want to try with 'latest' first to check if your configuration works well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was configure my StructuredStreaming with option `startingOffset=earliest`.
For this configuration, Spark will try to consume all the data available in Kafka stream and write it to HDFS once.
This takes a lot of time if the stream topic is gigantic.

For handling problem of too many small files, there are 2 options:

- configure the structured streaming with `triggerMode(processingTime=interval_definition)`
- configure the structured streaming with `triggerMode(once=True)` and schedule to start the Spark Application (I use Airflow to do this)